# c++ boost filesystem remove_all exception The directory is not empty

Tags: c++, windows, boost

I'm using boost 1.61 on Windows and I'm trying to remove a directory using `boost::filesystem::remove_all()` after checking it's a directory. It works some of the time but other times I get an exception thrown

`"boost::filesystem::remove The directory is not empty:"` with the path to directory I'm trying to delete.

The path is correct and when I get this exception, I check the folder and find that there are no files in there. I've checked the boost library implementation and found that on Windows it calls `RemoveDirectoryW` which says

> The path of the directory to be removed. This path must specify an
> empty directory, and the calling process must have delete access to
> the directory.

Given that the folder was empty when I checked it, what else could cause this to fail?

Comment: Hidden files, i.e. the folder appeared empty when it wasn't.